# Delete duplicate word in a line using a regular expression

Tags: regex

I want to delete duplicate word in a line.

For example:

```
arraythis1, XdashedSmall, Small, Medium, Large, XdashedLarge, XdashedSmall, Small, Medium, Large, XdashedLarge
```

I want to remove all of the duplicated items, turning the line into this:

```
arraythis1, XdashedSmall, Small, Medium, Large
```

My regex is like this: `\w(\D+)(?:,\s+\1\b,)+/gm`, See [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/oV2aO0/1).

Comment: What's your actual input and expected output?

Comment: but Small is duplicated in your output.... :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(\b[^,]+),(?=.*\b\1\b)
```

Try this.Replace by `empty string`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sJ9gM7/6

Comment: You might want to use `(\b[^\n,]+),(?=.*\b\1\b)`, to avoid new lines being added to the duplicated items to remove.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of your exact input, but given this example, if you just want to remove the first "arraythis1", you can just use this regular expression:

```
   ^[^\,]*
```

- The first carrot ("^") says "start at the front of the line".
- The square brackets ("[]") says to match a single character not present in the list (which is in the square brackets).
- I reverse the square brackets (instead of matching a single character, **don't match** a single character) by using another carrot in front of the list.
- and finally, I use an asterisk ("*") to make sure that I get all of the characters that **are not** a comma by making sure that I capture them all.

Then finally, to make the last of your regular expression, you will want to remove the remaining space (or spaces).

```
^[^\,]*,\s+
```

See https://regex101.com/r/oV2aO0/2

Comment: not delete the `arraythis1, ` see my output, that would be the result

Comment: @j2query What language are you using? This is something that you shouldn't use a regex for.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this

```
var words = new HashSet<string>();
string text = "arraythis1, XdashedSmall, Small, Medium, Large, XdashedLarge, XdashedSmall, Small, Medium, Large, XdashedLarge";
text = Regex.Replace(text, "\\w+", m =>
                 words.Add(m.Value.ToUpperInvariant())
                     ? m.Value
                     : String.Empty);
```